# connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sock'

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

I'm getting below error when trying to connect to routers and i'm running latest version of Paramiko. What could be causing this error and is there any workaround ?

Update:
its simple scriptusing ansible to collect "show system uptime" command output.

I have inventory files which contains ip address of routers

```
$ cat uptime.yaml 
---
- name: Get device uptime
  hosts:
    - all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  
  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: UsernName
      private: no
    
    - name: password
      prompt: Password
      private: yes

  tasks:
    - name: get uptime using ansible moduel
      junos_command:
        commands:
          - show system uptime
        provider:
          host: "{{ansible_host}}"
          port: 22
          username: "{{ username }}"
          password: "{{ password }}"

>>> print(paramiko.__version__)
2.7.2


[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Ansible will require Python 3.8 or newer on the controller starting with Ansible 2.12. Current version: 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) [GCC 8.4.0]. This feature 
will be removed from ansible-core in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
UsernName: regress
Password: 

PLAY [Get device uptime] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [get uptime using ansible moduel] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: ['connection local support for this module is deprecated and will be removed in version 2.14, use connection ansible.netcommon.netconf']
fatal: [R1_re0]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sock'"}
fatal: [R2_re0]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sock'"}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
R1_re0                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
R2_re0                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi Jay, please do share the code as well, where you are calling the `connect()` function.

Comment: Hi @SammyJ, I have updated my post with code. python version 3.6.9

Comment: Have you tried using the [`ansible.netcommon.netconf` connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/netcommon/netconf_connection.html) as suggested in your very explicit warning message as well as in the [official `junos_command` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/junipernetworks/junos/junos_command_module.html#parameter-provider) ?

Comment: @Zeitounator, Yes i tried that but i get this warning and it failed with same error. ```[WARNING]: provider is unnecessary when using ansible.netcommon.netconf and will be ignored ```